# Event delegation/propagation with jquery on landing page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a simple landing page for MOBILE with jQuery owl carousal. Several banners changing every 3 seconds. The problem is that i realized anchor tag does not redirect properly. If i scroll several times in the carousal, i need to click 2 times in order to activate the attr and redirect.

I added a custom JS script in order to make the redirection with an event instead of an anchor tag, but even though this works and redirects the page, it still has the same problem with clicking.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
  <body>
    <div class="promation">
      <section class="banner-section">
        <div class="owl-carousel main-banner-carousel banner-container" data-interval="false">
          <a class="test" href="#" data-href="" 
          ><img class="banner-container-img" src="main-banner-1.jpg"
          /></a>
          <a class="test" href="#" data-href="" 
          ><img class="banner-container-img" src="main-banner-2.jpg"
          /></a>
          <a class="test" href="#" data-href=""
          ><img class="banner-container-img" src="main-banner-3.jpg"
          /></a>
          <a class="test" href="#" data-href=""
          ><img class="banner-container-img" src="main-banner-4.jpg"
          /></a>
          <a class="test" href="#" data-href=""
          ><img class="banner-container-img" src="main-banner-5.jpg"
          /></a>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="counter-section" style="text-align: center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="bottom_txt"><h2>Jogos de caça-níqueis favoritos</h2></div>
          <div class="slideshow">        
            <div class="owl-carousel games-carousel slideshow-container">
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
              <a href=""><img src="random.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="owl-carousel bottom-banner-carousel second-banner">         
              <a href=""/></a>
              <a href=""/></a>           
          </div>
          <div class="buttons">
            <a href=""/></a>
            <a href=""/></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.test', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
          window.location.href = url;
        });     
      });
    </script>
    <script src="slides.js"></script>
  </body>
```

`slides.js` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var mainBannerCarousel = $('.main-banner-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 0,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 4500,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    items: 1,
  });

  var gamesCarousel = $('.games-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    dots: false,
    touchDrag: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 3000,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive: {
      280: {
        items: 3
      },
      768: {
        items: 3
      },
      800: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  });

  var bottomBannerCarousel = $('.bottom-banner-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    dots: false,
    touchDrag: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 6500,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    items: 1,
  });

  mainBannerCarousel.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    mainBannerCarousel.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    mainBannerCarousel.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
  });

  gamesCarousel.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    gamesCarousel.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    gamesCarousel.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
  });

  bottomBannerCarousel.on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
    bottomBannerCarousel.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
    bottomBannerCarousel.trigger('play.owl.autoplay');
  });
});
```

Comment: FWIW, you back/forward anchors are all invalid HTML. You are closing the anchor with / then you are also closing again it with `</a>`. This isn't your problem but you should replace them with `<a href=""></a>`

Comment: Im actually closing the img tag, that's why. I use to do it like that even though it's not necessary